# How fat is this dwarf?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

According to the wiki's page on [weapons and size](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/Weapons#Weapons_and_Size), dwarves must meet a certain minimum body size before they are capable of wielding many weapon types. This has thrown an entirely new, unexpected level of complexity into forming a militia, as the only references to a dwarf's size I can find are limited to vague adjectives such as "large", "thin", or "massive".

**How can I precisely determine the size of my dwarves** so I can draft the most effective servicedwarves? I'm not averse to using external methods such as DFHack.

Comment: I don't think fatness matters when it comes to wielding weapons, only their "base" height and width. I do believe fat provides some protection against conventional weapons, but makes dwarves much more susceptible to fire and explosions. Some players actually expose dwarves to controlled amounts of heat to melt the fat (This should be a product in the real world. Roast while you sleep!).

Comment: @kotekzot "Fat" was mostly just an attempt at being funny. Thanks for the adverse/averse fix, I never knew I was using the wrong word!

Answer (score 7):

**Size is something that is not currently viewable in the vanilla game**, nor is it precisely understood how the various size strings, (e.g., "rippling with untold amounts of lard" vs. "gigantic build, but very skinny") stack up.

External and 3rd party applications can potentially read this data, and in some cases, change it. [Runesmith](http://www.bay12forums.com/smf/index.php?topic=59056.0) was one such utility, but it is far from being up to date, and I don't know of any more recently updated utilities that allow what you're looking for.